# DownloadManager setVisibleInDownloadsUi not working

Tags: android, android-notifications, android-download-manager

I'm using DownloadManager in order to download and it is working great. However when I set setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false) the progress notification is still displayed.

```
Request request = new Request(Uri.parse(url));
request.setVisibleInDownloadsUi(false);
mDownloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

In my **Manifest** I've added the following permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DOWNLOAD_WITHOUT_NOTIFICATION" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Notification` is controlled [via `setNotificationVisibility()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html#setNotificationVisibility%28int%29), not `setVisibleInDownloadsUi`()`, according to the documentation.